# Spivak, courant and Apostol for beginners

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Are the above books : spivak, courant and apostol good even for beginners in calculus? I mean do they build up your basics before plunging into hardcore calculus.

And also about writing proofs : This is an integral part of these math books, my question will these books teach u how to write proofs or do we learn this separately?

Comment: I am not familiar to `courant` but I feel for beginners we have: $$\text{Spivak}\ggg\text{Apostol}\gg\text{courant}$$. :-)

Comment: Pretty sure Courant is first and Spivak second.